# Send application/x-www-form-urlencoded in Ktor

Tags: kotlin, urlencode, ktor

I can't figure out how to send a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` `POST` request in Ktor. I see some `submitForm` helpers in  Ktor's documentation but they don't send the request as expected.

What I want is to replicate this curl line behavior:

```
curl -d "param1=lorem&param2=ipsum" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" \
     https://webservice/endpoint
```

My dependency is on `io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:1.0.0`.

Answer (score 38):

After several tries I managed to send the request with the following code:

```
val url = "https://webservice/endpoint"
val client = HttpClient()
return client.post(url) {
    body = FormDataContent(Parameters.build {
        append("param1", "lorem")
        append("param2", "ipsum")
    })
}
```

Comment: I was stuck with this for a while now, and your solution worked great. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! There are so many ways to do this... This seems to be the simplest!

Answer (score 6):

```
val response: HttpResponse = client.submitForm(
    url = "http://localhost:8080/get",
    formParameters = Parameters.build {
        append("first_name", "Jet")
        append("last_name", "Brains")
    },
    encodeInQuery = true
)



https://ktor.io/docs/request.html#form_parameters
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Looking for information I found the way to do it

```
suspend inline fun <reified T> post(path: String, requestBody: FormDataContent): T {
    return apiClient.post() {
        url {
            encodedPath = path
            contentType(ContentType.Application.FormUrlEncoded)
        }
        setBody(requestBody)
    }.body()
}
```